# Git Failed During Push And Now Says Up To Date

Tags: git, egit

I'm using egit with Eclipse and during my commit/push something happened, the push failed and now it says everything is up to date, yet the repo does not have my commit (its not shown in the Github UI) and I can't commit it again because the files that are different it thinks are the same.

Output of git status:

```
git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store
#   runwaysdk-client/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs
#   runwaysdk-common/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs
#   runwaysdk-main/doc/scrum_notes.txt
#   runwaysdk-manager/target/
#   runwaysdk-server/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

The files that it listed I want to keep as untracked, one of the files that differs from the repo is `runwaysdk-test/pom.xml` but as you can see it wasn't listed as different.

I "think" that the commit worked, which would mean that the repo on my machine should have one more commit than what the remote repo (github) has, I just somehow need to push it?

```
git push
Everything up-to-date


git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:terraframe/Runway-SDK.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:terraframe/Runway-SDK.git (push)
```

How in the world do I fix this?

**Edit:**

git log shows that my latest commit was indeed comitted successfully to my local repo.

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch` after the failed push? This should update the remote refs.

Comment: Yeah, `git fetch` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github had some trouble with a fileserver today. You were probably affected by that.

Your commit should be there. If it does not show up in the web-ui after refreshing the page (and emptying your browser cache), please contact support@github.com about it.