# Egit files pushed to master don't show on github, but appear in clone of repo

Tags: push, clone, egit

Using Egit 3.0, I did a "Pull" to get latest master from github. Merged local changes into master and committed. Then did a "Push To Upstream." During the push I got a timeout warning. I could not see my commit or changed files when browsing github so I  tried push again - message "Master: master up to date." Tried pull again - message "No ref to fetch from origin - everything up to date." Still not seeing changes or commit on github. Went to another machine and did a pull from master. All of the changes and new files are in that pull! I then did a new clone of the master. All the changes are in that as well.  Any idea why the files are not showing up on the github site and how to get them to appear?

Comment: May be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17556300/305973) (GitHub having some server problems).

Answer (score 0):

Github the cleared cache and fixed the problem!
I contacted support at github.com on this issue and they responding saying that they "cleared the cache." Now I can see my new and changed files on the github site. It's is more often the case that user error is responsible for issues like this, but this time it seems it was something that support needed to do.